# Extracting value with beautifulsoup get_text() problem

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a single "value" **$82.76** from the code below.

```
<div class="MuiBox-root jss40 metric price">
    <h6 class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h6 MuiTypography-colorTextSecondary">HEC Price</h6>
    <h5 class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h5">$82.76</h5>
</div>
```

My code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('HectorDAO.mhtml', 'r') as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    
    tags = soup.find('h6', text='HEC Price')
    tag = tags.next_sibling.get_text()
    print(tag)
```

I expect **$82.76** but somehow I get strange output

```
$8= 
2.76
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Which version of python/beautifulsoup are you using? I'm not able to replicate with your provided HTML snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tags = soup.find('h6', text='HEC Price')
tag = tags.find_next_sibling().get_text()
print(tag)
```

It might work if you call `find_next_sibling()` instead.

Also try `quopri`:

```
from quopri import decodestring
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('HectorDAO.mhtml', 'r') as html_file:
    content = decodestring(html_file.read()).decode()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    
    tags = soup.find('h6', text='HEC Price')
    tag = tags.find_next_sibling().get_text()
    print(tag)
```

Or try both, MHTML can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks, quopri does the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

Changing '.next_sibling' to '.find_next_sibling()' does the trick.

```
content = html_file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find('h6', text='HEC Price')
tag = tags.find_next_sibling().get_text()
print(tag)
```

EDIT:

I would not recommend using nested .next_sibling as find_next_sibling() does this for you. See [Documentation.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling)